# Como ejecutar un test de Katalon sin entrar al IDE

Tags: test

Como dice el titulo quería saber si existe la posibilidad de ejecutar un test realizado por Katalon Studio sin la necesidad de entrar al IDE y ejecutarlo, de algún manera como si fuese un .exe o algo mas practico????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazlo como script (.bat o .sh). Cuando creas tu test case ya sea graándolo o programándolo tú mismo, al lado del botón de run existe un otón para generar una serie de comandos CMD, generas los comandos, los copias y los pegas en un archivo de texto y le cambias la extension a .bat. Por ejemplo: (Perdón no sé ocupar bloques)

C:
cd C:\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-X.X.0
katalon -runMode=console -projectPath="C:\Users\YO\Katalon Studio\CarpetaProyecto\MiProyecto.prj" -reportFileName="report" -retry=0 -testSuiteCollectionPath="Test Suites/MiProyecto"

En proyectpath colocas el directorio en donde ejejcutas Katalon Studio y en testSuiteCollectionPath, el test suite collection que geneas con Katalon. Héchale un vistazo a la documentación